# how to check string for first character occured in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3ye1.png)**8200ifix**

- Need to check the first occuring numbers  until character came  Any
  way to take character as checking point . before character all must
  be digits
- i know with slice property  is there any generic way to check
  numericals until and unless first character occured
- is it possible to write regexp in mysql for this kind of logic ?

Comment: yes possible but can you show some code that you tried? Moreover you should add an example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cast`:

```
SELECT CAST(field AS UNSIGNED)
FROM   mytable
```

This will return 0 if there are no digits at the start of the value. The non-digits that follow in the field, and everything after those, are ignored. So for "1234abc567de" you'll get 1234.

In JavaScript you can use `parseInt(field, 10)` in much the same way. It will return `NaN` if there is no digit in the first position.

Comment: need to check if character is not a alphabet !!

Comment: An alphabet is a series of characters.... which character you want to check? The first? Maybe it is easier if you put sample data and expected output in your question. Note that alphabetical characters will be ignored by this `cast` and `parseInt`.